# What was Sherlock about to remark about Molly's boyfriend?

Tags: sherlock

At the end of *The Empty Hearse*, when Sherlock meets Tom who was Molly's boyfriend, he stares at him long enough to remark something but eventually resigns to a handshake with him. Once he gets out of the room John seems to acknowledge him that its good he didn't mention it.

I only saw the episode once, Can anyone enlighten me as to what were they talking about?

Comment: I thought it was because she picked someone with similar characteristics as Sherlock.

Comment: I thought he could be the Sherlock lookalike he was talking about earlier. In Sherlock's faked death theory he mentioned how they used a second body that looked just like him. Then he said Molly found him and did all the death record stuff.
Tom looks exactly like Sherlock and has the same coat (Sherlock said he has lots of coats and the body they used wore one of them). Molly met him therough friends: Sherlock is a friend.
Just a theory ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- The long coat,
- the scarf,
- the shoes,
- the curly hair,
- the high cheekbones

Molly's fiancé Tom clearly resembles someone ...

**Tom**

[image: Tom]

[image: Tom]

**Sherlock**

[image]

Comment: I am so embarrassed that I missed this.

Answer (score 11):

He was observing that Tom was dressed just like Sherlock.  Watson had also noticed the similarity in clothing style.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add something more with [Oliver_C's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16373/6895). After Sherlock came out of room he put on a scarf

[image]

and exhales how similar is Tom to him.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Could it be possible that Tom is actually the mysterious third brother of Sherlock and Mycroft? In the third episode when questioned if he had familiar brotherly compassion, Mycroft responded: "don't be absurd.... you know what happened to the other one". So there is a third brother and there is a certain possibility that it is Tom. To catch Sherlock's attention for so long and so intensely it had to be of something significant more than dressing like him. That is my theory.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16645/is-there-a-third-holmes-sibling