# Doesn't Sherlock's comment to Watson during their good bye scene suggest that there is/was a third Holmes sibling and that the sibling is a woman?

Tags: sherlock

Thanks to Oliver for the correct wording. I played back the stream more than once but didn't get it right. As for failing to follow the rules about comments, while I understand the need for courtesy & procedures in online forums, the rules of Stack Exchange make me feel as if I am in a Medieval court of law, and will never manage to figure out which writ I should plead.

So I will bow out, wishing you all well, with apologies for my unseemly behavior.

In the question ["Is there a third Holmes sibling?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16645/49) the questioner mentions a comment Mycroft made, saying "I'm not given to brotherly love,..." Later in the episode, when Holmes is saying good bye to John beside the airplane, Sherlock says that his brother and sister used to sing a song about the wind to him.

The comments made by Mycroft and Sherlock suggest that the series writers have a Holmes sister in mind. It'll be interesting if she shows up in the next season of the show. It would also add an interesting counterpoint to the fact that John has a sister from whom he is seriously estranged. (Sister Harry didn't accept her invitation to John and Mary's wedding.)

I would have made a comment about this where the question about a third sibling appeared, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately your post as it stands is indeed not a complete question at the moment. You seem to answer the question from the title already in the question body, so what actually is it you want to know? While your insights might be informative, they would maybe have fit better as a comment on the other question. If you don't have enough reputation to comment yet, feel free to earn some (you only need 50, or an existing account on another SE with at least 200).

Comment: Not sure where you heard `sister`. What Sherlock said: _The East Wind takes us all in the end. ... It’s a story my brother told me when we were kids. The East Wind, this terrifying force that lays waste to all in its path. Seeks out the unworthy and plucks them from the earth. That was generally me... He was a rubbish big brother._

Comment: *"have no clue how else a low-rep member can participate in a discussion"* - You can always comment on your own questions. Other than that, [trying to get clues](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) also helps the situation.