# What did Mycroft mean when he said: "You know what happened to the other-one"

Tags: dialogue, sherlock

At the end of *Sherlock* S03E03, Mycroft says to man standing beside him: "Don't be absurd, I am not given to some brotherly compassion. You know what happened to the other-one", and the man seemed convinced with his point.

Comment: You'll like this Reddit thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/Sherlock/comments/1wf2zs/spoilers_mycroft_dont_be_absurd_i_am_not_given_to/

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16645/49.